# Why is my Do and while function closing the moment I input a value?

Tags: c

I am currently stuck on this block of code that seems to close automatically for any input I place into it? I've spent a good 15-18ish minutes, but I can't seem to figure out why. This syntax is straight from my C guide book too >.<"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int input = 0;
    do
    {
          input = scanf("%d", &input);
          printf("Hello!\n");

    } while( input < -1 || input > 10);
return 0;
}
```

Might I have some wrong syntax going here?

Comment: Post sample inputs you are using...

Comment: Your printf is missing a terminating `"` character.  Is this the actual code you're trying to compile and run?

Comment: This is the actual code, all I did was just rework it to fit my needs. I am using inputs like 5 or 15. Values in and out of the domain.

Comment: Wherever did you get the idea that scanf returns the value you want?

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong here:

`input = scanf("%d", &input);`

You are getting input in variable `input` but you are overwriting it with return value of `scanf`.

[`scanf` returns](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html) number of values successfully inputted or `EOF` if some error occurs while scanning first input.

hence whatever value you give as input, variable `input` gets value either `1` or `EOF`, therefore, your `do-while` loop may break.

You should use it like this:

```
int ret;
ret = scanf("%d", &input);
```

Answer (score 1):

`input = scanf("%d", &input);` will return `EOF` or `1`, as you are storing the result of `scanf` in `input` variable.

If you enter any integer value it will return `1` i.e number of input successfully read.

In your case you need to do the following:

```
int retval; 
retval = scanf("%d", &input);
```

Comment: In this case, confident that `scanf()` only returns `1` or `EOF`.

Comment: "The fscanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed." C11dr §7.21.6.2 16.  Ia a non-space, non-digit (and not +,-) is entered, no conversion occurs and EOF is returned, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Function `scanf` either returns EOF or the number of items that were assigned. In your code the only one item, input, is assigned. So in case of success function scanf returns 1. 1 is greater than -1 and less than `0. So it is unimportant what number you will type. In any case scanf will return 1.

From the description of the function in the C Standard

> 3 The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input
>   failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed.
>   Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items
>   assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the
>   event of an early matching failure.

Change this statement

```
input = scanf("%d", &input);
```

where you reassign input after scanf execution to

```
scanf("%d", &input );
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d",&input);`  it accept value in input variable

but `input=scanf("%d",&input);` assign 1 always to the variable `input` because `scanf()` function returns number of parameter it accepts.